# incrementing pointer returned by C malloc

Tags: c++, malloc

I'm using malloc to allocate enough memory to store 100 string*:

```
string** ptr = (string**)malloc(100*sizeof(string*));
```

Then I put a string* value into each cell:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
    ptr[i*sizeof(string*)] = stringdata[i]; // stringdata is a vector<string*>
}
```

In the above for loop, I didn't do ptr[i], because I understand each ptr increment is always by 1 byte, but sizeof(string*) could be more than 1 byte.

However, I have seen other people's code where they simply use ptr[i] without the additional sizeof(string*). Does anyone know why this is also ok?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is `string`, please? Or should it be you are doing C++ but C?

Comment: sorry, yes, I used C malloc but for C++ programs. Thanks

Comment: are you talking about std::string? if so shouldn't you be using `new`? it is an object as far as I remember

Comment: If you are using std::string, use <vector> to store it!

Comment: You should explain why you *really* need to use `malloc`. It is probably a *very bad* idea.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this example:

```
int i[2] = {0};   
int* ptr;
ptr = i; // pointer aims to i[0]
ptr++; // pointer aims to i[1]
```

ptr is defined as an int pointer. If sizeof(int) is 4, ptr++ will move the pointer 4 btyes, because this is sizeof(int) and the pointer is a int pointer. If ptr was a char pointer and sizeof(char) is 4 bytes, then ptr++ adds only 1 byte.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Another related question is that if I have (void**) ptr = (void**)malloc(100*sizeof(void*)), I seem to have trouble doing pointer arithmetic on void**. In that case, I tend to work with memory address directly (i.e. converting void** to size_t to get absolute memory address, and then add required number of bytes). But thsi approach seems very "low-level", is there a better way? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Consider this example:

```
char* cptr = malloc(12);
int* iptr = (int*)cptr;
```

Now `iptr + 1` points to the same memory location as `cptr + 4`.

For typed pointers the compiler always counts whole elements, not individual characters.

Answer (score 2):

When indexing an array, it will always add the size of the arrays type. So for example, if we have an array of integers

```
int array[10];
```

Doing `array[1]` will add `sizeof(int) * 1` to the base pointer `array`. So if the array is on address `0x100` (simplified) then the address of `array[1]` will be `0x104` if the size of `int` is 4.

---

However, in your case you seem to be using C++ `std::string`, in which case I would recommend using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of arrays. Like

```
std::vector<std::string> strings;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to multiply an index by the `sizeof` each element!

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
  ptr[i] = stringdata[i]; // stringdata is a vector<string*>
}
```

And mixing `malloc` and `new` is a very bad manner. Stick to `new` in C++.

```
string** ptr = new string*[100];
```

<sup>`::operator new` often (but *not always* !) is calling `malloc`</sup>

At last, consider using `std::vector<std::string>` for `ptr`.

Comment: I would suggest to him to use vector<string> instead of the mess he did

Answer (score 1):

You've declared "ptr" as being "string **".  This gives the compiler enough information that, when you use array indexing, it can compute the memory locations for you.  If you had declared "ptr" as a "char *" (ie. a block of undistinguished memory), you would need to do the offset calculations yourself.